# Agrupar y Promediar precio en array

Tags: php, array

Estoy recorriendo un loop con información que contiene una lista de precio con su año de venta.

Me gustaría agrupar por lista de precio año y promediar los precios en un nuevo array. Para luego buscar y agregar en un nuevo array su precio promedio.

El precio promedio se debe condicionar mediante Lista de precio y Año.

```
<?php

$data = [
        array(
            'lista_precio' => 1,
            'ano' => '2021',
            'precio' => 500
        ),
        array(
            'lista_precio' => 1,
            'ano' => '2021',
            'precio' => 500
        ),
        array(
            'lista_precio' => 2,
            'ano' => '2021',
            'precio' => 1000
        ),
        array(
            'lista_precio' => 1,
            'ano' => '2022',
            'precio' => 1000
        )
    ];
    
 
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $ano = $row['ano'];
    /*Nuevo array con la agrupación y precio*/
}

/*Creamos un nuevo array con su precio promedio */

foreach ($data as $fila) {
    $ano             = $fila['ano'];
    $lista_precio    = $fila['lista_precio'];
    /*Obtener precio promedio mediante lista_precio y ano*/
    $data_paquetes[] = array(
        'lista_precio' => $fila['lista_precio'],
        'ano' => $fila['ano'],
        'precio' => $fila['precio'],
        'precio_promedio' => ????
    );
    
}
```

https://onecompiler.com/php/3xtjcb2ye

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Buen día, podrías agregar un ejemplo de lo que esperas tener al final? Deseas calcular el promedio de precios en cada año? Es decir, si tienes 2021 como año, quieres que el promedio sea ((500+500+1000)/3)? O quieres que el promedio se calcule por año y por lista de precio? Qué intentas hacer en el primer `foreach`? Porque luego estas sobreescribiendo `$ano` en el segundo `foreach`

Comment: No te has explicado demasiado bien... ¿que prevalece?  ¿tu codigo en esta pregunta o el código del enlace que nos has pasado? ¿o ninguno de los dos y quieres la solución sea cual fuere en lo que esté basado?  Normalmente intentamos arreglar el código que nos proporcionan en la pregunta, pero no se cual quieres que sea la base de esta pregunta. Veo que cualquiera puede modificar el código de ese enlace, y quizas por eso no se parecen ahora ambos, je.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato saber el promedio x lista_precio y ano. ejemplo lista_precio =>1 (500+500)/2;

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona, pero no me convence aun:

```php
$sumas = [];
$items = [];

foreach ($data as $arr) {
    if (isset($sumas[$arr['ano']][$arr['lista_precio']])) {
        $sumas[$arr['ano']][$arr['lista_precio']] += $arr['precio'];
        $items[$arr['ano']][$arr['lista_precio']]++;
    } else {
        $sumas[$arr['ano']][$arr['lista_precio']] = $arr['precio'];
        $items[$arr['ano']][$arr['lista_precio']] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($sumas as $ano => $registros) {
    foreach ($registros as $lista_precio => $sumaprecios) {
        $promedio[$ano][$lista_precio] = $sumaprecios/$items[$ano][$lista_precio];
    }
}

print_r($promedio);
```

Esto devuelve este array:

```php
Array
(
    [2021] => Array
        (
            [1] => 500
            [2] => 1000
        )

    [2022] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1000
        )

)
```

Me reservo mi derecho a mejorarlo :-)